# Is it possible to download file from Github Wiki in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, github

I am working in private repository that has Wiki pages with zip files that was pushed to Wiki only not to main repo. So now I'm trying to arrange a Powershell script that download zip file from this Wiki.

I followed the script at: [StackeOverflow: PowerShell to download Zip file from GitHub API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66428571/1144952) and everywhere else but always, always get this **404 Not found** error when `Invoke-WebRequest` try to actually  download file.

I have a direct link to zip file: `https://github.com/enterprise/repo/wiki/Folder/file.zip` (I assure you this link download file from any web browser without any hiccups. From Chrome it **always** succeed)

but whatever credentials I enter or whatever I change the download link to - it **always** fails with **404 Not Found** error. In Chrome browser 'Network' tab I see that it does redirect to `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/enterprise/repo/Folder/file.zip?token=ASZER2VYQDOVBN46TXVK2BWTU3` but it does not happened in Powershell script (?)

I really appreciate a small example of Powershell script for private repo.

Thank you !